# Нужны ли вопросы по настройке ПО или администрированию на Stack Overflow на русском?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, тематика

Как мы знаем, Stack Overflow на русском - это в первую очередь сообщество профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения и энтузиастов программирования. Иногда случается, что нам необходим совет в настройке сложного программного обеспечения или по администрированию серверов.

Было бы здорово найти решение проблемы среди коллег. К тому же, с большой вероятность, кругозор участников Stack Overflow на русском достаточно широк, чтобы покрыть данные тематики. Более того, бывает, что подобные вопросы ни чуть не проще вопросов разработки ПО, а иногда даже более интересные.

С другой стороны, нам, как программистам, не хотелось бы допускать потока вопросов не относящихся напрямую к нашей профессии.

Как поступить? Нужны ли нам вопрос по администрированию и настройке ПО? Если да, то почему и как отличить вопросы, которые будут полезны и интересны сообществу, от тех, которым не место на сайте?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Определив сейчас, что подобные вопросы не являются тематическими для сообщества, мы лишим себя возможности сбора информации по данным темам в формате “вопрос/решение” на долгое время. Компания Stack Exchange объявила, что планирует запуск исключительно сообществ по программированию на языках, отличных от английского. Как результат, даже при большом желании у нас не получится вынести данные вопросы на специализированную площадку. Более того, опыт Сети Знаний показывает, что идея деления на небольшие форумы при текущем размере сообщества ошибочна.

Подобные вопросы будут полезны сообществу, потому что в процессе работы мы часто сталкиваемся с интересными задачами из смежных областей. “Узкое” место -  набор критериев, с помощью которых мы бы смогли относить вопрос к тематическим/нетематическим для сообщества. Как мне кажется, совершенно точно такими критериями не могут быть сложность (вопрос всегда простой, когда знаешь ответ) и определенные технологии или разделы знаний (windows, linux и т. д.).

Вопросы, публикуемые в сообществе должны соответствовать следующим критериям.

- **Профессиональность**. Stack Overflow на русском создан с целью обмена узкоспециализированными профессиональными знаниями за счет помощи коллегам в решении повседневных рутинных задач. Ответы на такие вопросы повышают нашу квалификацию. Например, вопрос об организации RAID массивов будет тематическим, но вопрос о покупке нового винчестера - нет.
- **Значимость знаний**. Публикуемые вопросы должны иметь большую ценность для сообщества в целом (как минимум, возможность использования решения многократно). Здесь очень важна постановка вопроса - он должен быть сформулирован так, чтобы знатоки хотели опубликовать развернутый ответ. Зачастую количество и качество ответов на вопрос зависят от его постановки.
- **Ярко выраженная специфика отрасли**. Вопрос должен быть такого уровня, чтобы неспециалист не мог в нем разобраться. Например, вопрос про удаление ПО из ОС Windows следует закрывать/удалять как нетематический, но вопрос про настройку IIS через пользовательский интерфейс для интеграции с приложением ASP.NET с большой вероятностью будет полезны сообществу.

Comment: *"Компания Stack Exchange объявила, что планирует запуск исключительно сообществ по программированию на языках, отличных от английского."* — а вот это уже **критически важная информация**. Я так понимаю, следует понимать так: даже если будут толпы желающих создать новый сайт — SF на другому языке, — то вы его не дождётесь. На SOPT сисадминство объявили оффтопиком, пытались создать аналог SF через Зону 51, очень быстро набрали требуемое количество желающих, но Stack Exchange в одностороннем порядке закрыло идею, предложим постить всё вместе, чем вызвало бунт. Пока что SOPT = SO + Programmers.

Comment: А есть вариант открыть это на другом движке? Или не взлетит?

Comment: @SmitJohnth видимо(-невидимо) придется регатся на "Тостере"Большое сообщество, можно задавать вопросы любые, даже филосовские или что то вроде "диета для программистов"

Comment: @silksofthesoul тостер и не взлетел

Comment: @SmitJohnth ...а вроде ничего так.. взлетел. я им иногда пользуюсь даже. ...и ответов довольно много особенно на простецкие вопросы. и поисковики порой выкидывают на ответы с того сервиса.

Comment: @SmitJohnth У нас уже был неудачный опыт "открытия" сайтов по разнообразным тематикам, начиная от моды и заканчивая английским языком. На мой взгляд, оптимальный вариант - имея перед собой успешный опыт Stack Overflow на английском, двигаться в избранном _нами_ направлении одним сообществом.

Comment: @silksofthesoul задавал там пару вопросов. Ничем не лучше форумов. На гугл мне плевать.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не понял. Предлагаете вместо вопросов по администрированию/софту задавать вопросы про программирование? :)

Answer (score 9):

Все довольно просто. Берем сферического программиста в вакууме. И смотрим с чем ему приходится сталкиваться в процессе работы:

- ide. К примеру, миграция с Eclipse на Android Studio у многих вызывала вопросы.
- vcs. Начиная с работы с github'ом и различными workflow, заканчивая установкой, настройкой локальных серверов.
- ci. Ответы по этой тематике могут дать реально опытные люди.
- dbms. Разворачивание, настройка, администрирование.
- apache nginx и проч. ЧПУ, борьба с DDOS.
- наверняка еще что-то не упомянул...

Кроме того, есть вопросы касающиеся непосредственно администрирования, и программистам иногда также приходится сталкиваться или интересоваться администрированием. Начиная от настройки локальной сетки дома, заканчивая, даже не знаю чем... - сисадмины подскажут лучше (мне, например, приходилось удаленно настраивать систему видеонаблюдения с публикацией видео в облако).

ЗЫ Желающие обсудить пони и кваку могут это сделать в чате...

Comment: А еще виртуалки/контейнеры, CM-тулы вроде ansible/chef/puppet, баш-скриптинг, разные toolchain-ы, джиры-стэши-рэдмайны-герриты и т. п.

Comment: @Nofate угу, причем чем уже специализация, тем сложнее проблема и ценнее ответ.

Answer (score 6):

Думаю такие вопросы нужны. Проблема в том, как, действительно, определить полезность/бесполезность такого вопроса для сообщества, т.к. такой анализ всегда субъективен. Возможно, если вопрос без конкретики, например, "После апдейта все упало, что делать?", то такой вопрос однозначно бесполезен. Если же вопрос содержит конкретное описание ошибки, с логами и т.п., то возможно стоит такие вопросы оставлять, т.к. хоть это и сообщество программистов, но проблемы непосредственно с ПО бывают у каждого из нас.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, такие вопросы допустимы. Я понимаю, что большинство из них  не вписываются  в рамки глобальной задачи накопления знаний, но они важны для конкретного человека именно сейчас. Почему бы не помочь ему, если возможно?

Мне кажется подобные вопросы должны быть доступны по крайней мере несколько недель, а вот потом (очевидно, что вопрос для автора становится уже неактуальным) "непрофильные вопросы" можно и удалять.

Comment: Очень странное предложение. Если вы всем скажете, что отвечать можно, но вопросы и ответы вместе с репой растворятся через неделю, то число желающих участвовать в "чате" сократится на порядок.

Comment: @Athari, ну, у нас с вами явно ортогональные взгляды на "хорошо-плохо".  Вы что, серьезно относитесь к "репе", считаете ее движущей силой?

Comment: Репа — очень важная составляющая часть мотивации. Но речь не только о ней. Помочь одному человеку с конкретной проблемой или помочь тысячам, которые найдут ответ в гугле — это тоже разница в мотивации. Желающих работать бесплатным саппортом вряд ли найдётся много.

Answer (score 1):

Раз никто больше не хочет, выскажу альтернативное мнение. Надо же узнать, как народ к нему относится.

Предлагаю **следовать правилам большого Stack Overflow**: если вопрос закрыли бы как оффтопик с рекомендацией задать вопрос на Super User или Server Fault — такой вопрос должен быть закрыт и на Stack Overflow на русском.

Это не означает закрытие всех вопросов про проблемы с установкой, конфигурацией и эксплуатацией приложений. На большом Stack Overflow разрешены вопросы относительно инструментов, которые в основном используются программистами: среды разработки, системы контроля версий и т.п. Разумеется, к ним применяются всё те же жёсткие критерии: вопрос "у меня не запускается IDE" без каких-либо деталей должен быть закрыт.

Вопросы "как настроить локальную сеть", "почему после обновления винды синий экран", "как настроить стили в ворде" и иже — оффтопик.

Причина простая: я не вижу большой активности в вопросах, касающихся администрирования. Их постоянно кто-то пытается закрывать. И в целом, сферический программист в вакууме — весьма паршивый системный администратор. Это слишком разные профессии, чтобы валить их в одну кучу.

Предложения следить за каждым вопросов для сисадминов, индивидуально предупреждать каждого автора вопроса в комментариях, а потом вручную закрывать — считаю абсолютно нереалистичными, потому что никто этим на постоянной основе заниматься не будет / не захочет. Подобные предложения принимаю только в компании с обещанием в ближайший год каждый день заходить на сайт и просматривать 100% вопросов по такой системе.

Comment: Аргумент "у нас должно быть как на SO" не канает. Сообщество другое, объединенное по другому признаку. И утонуть в админских вопросах не получится, хэшкод был объединен с руткодом как раз из-за низкой активности последнего и в том числе потому что на руткоде отвечали те же, кто был на хэшкоде, т.е. программеры (в той или иной степени). Если на админские вопросы не будут отвечать также часто и охотно, значит нет компетентных админов, что считаю делом времени. Если бы такие люди появились в сообществе и как можно больше и раньше, лично я был бы только рад.

Comment: Если мы с вами плохо знаем какую-либо тематику -- это не значит что все  вопросы к ней относящиеся должны быть удалены с сайта. Пока ServerFault вопросов (**профессиональное** администрирование) не слишком много -- можно их на Stack Overflow на русском оставить. К тому же есть DevOps, которым по должности положено и разрабатывать и администрировать и тестировать.