# Посты или комментарии, призывающие перестать пользоваться данным сайтом

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, комментарии, ответы, возможный-вред

Увидел [комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7200/#comment29089_7200), содержащий призывы перестать пользоваться данным сайтом. Также был точно такой же ответ того же автора, но он удалён (возможно был преобразован из ответа в комментарий, но я точно не знаю). Содержимое:

> Уважаемые пользователи, затронутые в этом конфликте! Призываю Вас взять внеплановый отпуск на пару месяцев - чтобы остудить голову и показать что будет с сообществом, без старичков. А потом посмотрим как будет идти рассуждение о полезности. Сам получил бан в чате за [абсолютно нейтральное сообщение](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhxeF.png), поэтому покидаю SO на неопределённое время. Не хочу находится в обществе с таким управлением, которое мы имеем на данный момент. Надеюсь, Вы успеете прочитать это до удаления этого сообщения. Спасибо, было приятно с Вами общаться.

Я посчитал, что таким комментариям не место здесь и отметил данный комментарий тревогой с просьбой вмешательства модератора и сообщением "На мой взгляд, призывы не пользоваться данным сайтом должны быть недопустимыми здесь.", которая была отклонена.

Рассматривая данный случай, хочется также задать общий вопрос: допустимы ли посты/комментарии, призывающие перестать пользоваться данным сайтом? Если да, то почему, раз они могут принести потенциальный вред данному ресурсу.

Comment: Да, ваше предположение верное, ответ был преобразован в комментарий.

Тут нужно определиться - есть тут свобода слова или нет. Если есть - то не вижу ничего крамольного в таком призыве, не насильно же будут людей от мониторов оттаскивать :-)

Намного хуже не сам призыв, но причины почему у такого комментария/ответа вообще есть поддержка?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Свобода должна идти бок-о-бок с ответственностью, иначе будет хаос. Свобода индивидуальности может быть источником проблем для других индивидуальностей, поэтому и существуют правила. Причины есть у любого поведения, даже самого агрессивного. Но здесь вопрос не про психологию и причины, а про соответствие правилам.

Comment: Комментарий был преобразован значит нарушений правил нет, разве не логично? :-)

Comment: @FoggyFinder Вообще не вижу взаимосвязи. Если в ответе будут, к примеру, маты или просто набор бессвязных букв, то это можно преобразовать в комментарий и забыть? Думаю, что нет. Поэтому есть и вопрос о допустимости.

Comment: То есть вы не доверяете текущим модераторам раз предполагаете наличие таких грубых ошибок, правильно? Если в ответе будут маты, то его просто отредактируют или удалят.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Это просто примеры. Я просто не вижу как именно перенос ответа в комментарий говорит о соответствии правилам.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov он не отвечал на вопрос, но относился к нему и не содержал ничего предосудительного. Если бы он был совершенно нерелевантным, неуместным или предосудительным, он был бы просто удалён.

Comment: Да не вмешивайтесь вы в конфликт. Отдельное предложение ничего не значит. Видел переписку или её часть - особо не вчитывался, сама фраза бросилась в глаза. По моему не стоит обсуждения. Сами разберутся. Забаненые уже есть.

Comment: @nick_n_a Давайте без перехода на личности и додумываний. Я тут вообще обсуждаю соответствие правилам такого рода призывов и всё. То, что вы, и не только вы, "конфликты" начинаете обсуждать — я не несу за это ответственности.

Answer (score 7):

Я считаю, что постам с критикой сайта место на сайте. В нормальном сообществе должен быть плюрализм мнений.

Я считаю, что запрещать высказывание того или иного мнения имеет право лишь консенсус участников (да и то в крайних случаях). Я считаю, что сообщество должно иметь право само устанавливать, что хорошо, а что плохо, что правильно, а что неправильно.

Если мы хотим, чтобы на сайте было много участников, нужно устранять то, что раздражает сообщество, а не закрывать от других нелицеприятные мнения и критику. Критика существует для того, чтобы сделать сайт лучше, даже если она и выражена в острой форме.

Мнение, о котором идё речь в вопросе, имеет прямое отношение к обсуждению работы сайта, и, следовательно, является онтопиком.
Площадка, которая пытается навязать мнения, не может быть хорошей площадкой.

Не убивайте StackOverflow.

Comment: На мой взгляд, призыв к неучастию в сообществе как раз и "убивает" StackOverflow.

Comment: Кстати, любое негативное сообщение, каким бы негативным и циничным оно ни было (даже явные оскобления), для некоторых людей может считаться "критикой" и "плюрализмом мнений".

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: На мой взгляд, необоснованные запреты убивают StackOverflow намного сильнее. Если SO и вправду настолько слаб, что один призыв покинуть его может привести к гибели, и поддерживать энтузиазм пользователей нужно административными мерами, то никто уже ничего не спасёт. (Я думаю, что это всё же неверное предположение.)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: Да, конечно. Если вы отвечаете на критику запретом критики, есть основание полагать, что критика была обоснованной.

Comment: призыв покинуть сайт это не конструктивная критика (назло маме уши отморожу). Обсуждение частных модераторских действий на stack overflow не следует допускать (масло в огонь). Публично можно правила, соглашения обсуждать, но сама модерация в частном порядке происходит. Конструктивно было бы конкретные вещи обсуждать. К примеру: сузить regex по удалению комментариев, с примером полезных комментариев, которые под него сейчас попадают или убрать "домашнее задание" причину закрытия как неверный сигнал посылающую, заменить на использование других причин закрытия и/или добавить "вопрос-список" итд.

Comment: @jfs: Конструктивная критика уместна тогда, когда есть диалог. На текущий момент, насколько мне видится, мнение сообщества не считается аргументом и игнорируется, поэтому особого смысла в приводить конструктивные аргументы нет.

Comment: @jfs Призыв покинуть сайт, конечно, эмоциональный и по здравому размышлению нет никаких оснований полагать что подобная акция положительно отразится на сообществе. Одно дело когда её поддерживает большинство участников, а другое - когда не наберется и десятка активистов.

Comment: @jfs Речь не о действиях модераторов, а о причинах побудивших их к такому действию. Например есть проблема удаления вопросов с меты. Как вы предлагаете ее решить если вопрос на мете об этом все равно удалят?

Comment: @VladD ничего принципиального с основания Stack Overflow не изменилось. Основатели всегда имели решающий голос, чтобы защитить своё видение сайта, при этом прислушиваясь к доводам и идеям от сообщества. Я уверен, что вы сможете привести примеры, когда обсуждения на Мете к изменениям вели. Если вы знаете  конкретные примеры когда компания во вред сообществу поступала, тогда есть о чём говорить.

Comment: @jfs , _вред сообществу_ это настолько субъективно, что я сомневаюсь что можно найти пример, который признаете вы. Для меня таким примером служит снятие овнеров главной румы, сообщество теперь не может свободно вести обсуждения там.

Comment: @GreenDragon вы утверждаете, что невозможно узнать есть ли консенсус в сообществе по какому-то конкретному вопросу? Это ложь. Пример: "разрешить вопросы по сисадминству" ([консенсус: за](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/225/23044)). А то что не всё совпадает с вашим личным мнением—это ожидаемо. С моим личным мнением также не всё на Stack Overflow совпадает.

Comment: что характерно. Вчера долго долго обсуждали, а конкретного примера непротиворечивого, по которому консенсус существует так и не привёл никто. То что легко пример на ум не приходит само по себе противоречит громким заявлениям, что не слушают. По факту: вопросов с меткой [tag:статус-отклонено] гораздо меньше чем [tag:статус-завершено].

Comment: @jfs, нет, я утверждаю не это. Это не ложь, а просто ваш домысел.  Немного разные вещи. Обсуждать есть смысл когда есть что сказать. Вам есть что сказать непосредственно по теме поднятого ТС вопроса в контексте этого ответа? Правильность или неправильность тех или иных решений компании и реакция на это сообщества, на мой взгляд, обсуждается или в обсуждении предложения/изменения или может выноситься отдельным вопросом, но только после сбора определенных данных.

Comment: ещё факты: сигнал/шум в комментариях у одной стороны и другой сравнить: где сигнал это проверяемые конкретными фактами утверждения, а шум это демагогия, которая на эмоциях пытается  играть, подавляя рациональные аргументы¶ Чисто формально измерить: отношение количество объективных тезисов (возможно неверных)/количество букв.

Comment: @jfs вы исходите из ложных предпосылок, когда ссылаетесь на статусы (завершено, отклонено). Сами по себе они ничего не значат. Посмотрите в статусе завершено очень много не предложений, а исправлений дефектов (в основном - переводом) силами сообщества (в основном alexolut). К тому-же если предложение утверждено, то это не значит что был приведен в исполнение самый популярный (с найбольшим числом голосов) вариант (что на самом деле понятно).

Comment: @jfs: Тем не менее, моё мнение состоит в том, что сообщество должно иметь финальное слово. И я его высказываю. Это тоже запрещено?

Comment: @jfs: Вы передёргиваете. Узнать, есть ли консенсус в сообществе по тому или иному вопросу, можно, если этому выяснению не противостоит администрация.

Comment: популизм, ноль фактов.

Comment: @jfs: Если вы уж переходите на личности, указывайте хоть к какой конкретно фразе у вас претензии.

Comment: @VladD На личности не перехожу. Не важно *кто* сказал, важно *что* было сказано/не сказано. Попробуйте сами посчитать  сигнал/шумом для комментариев как выше предложено и сделать свои выводы.

Comment: @VladD вы мне несколько точек зрения не моих приписали в комментариях, которые я смотрю люди не разбираясь плюсуют. Я не думаю, что вы это умышленно сделали, что вы специально "передёргиваете"¶ К примеру, мой комментарий явно говорит, что можно консенсус определить, поэтому зачем вы утверждаете как будто я противоположной точки зрения придерживаюсь, не ясно. Достаточно ли у вас integrity чтобы ошибку признать? (вот это можно переходом на личности считать. Прошлые обсуждения с вами указывают что вы способны к рациональной дискуссии без подлых приёмов)

Comment: @jfs , вот, опять, вы пишите что люди плюсуют не разбираясь. Это и есть переход на личности. Или я не прав и вы можете сказать кто и почему из плюсовавших не разобрался в словах VladD без популизма, но с фактами?

Comment: @jfs: А можно более конкретно, я вроде бы старался не приписывать вам ничего. Возможно, поскольку дискуссия переходит за рамки комментариев к вопросу, лучше перенести её в чат.

Comment: @VladD: *"можно более конкретно"* —продолжайте читать со слов *"К примеру"* в [моём предыдущем комментарии](https://goo.gl/dL8Ndx) он говорит о конкретной проблеме в [вашем предыдущем комментарии](https://goo.gl/PbHJpe). Куда уж конкретнее.

Comment: @jfs: Ну, «вы передёргиваете» — это ведь не приписывание вам какой-либо _точки зрения_, это (не вполне вежливое, да, простите) указание на то, что вы приводите, как мне кажется, не вполне верную информацию. Например, по вопросу о снятии владельцев чата в сообществе _был_ консенсус, но никто этот консенсус не _опросил_ у сообщества. (Это к обсуждению того, бывает ли явный консенсус.)

Comment: @VladD: Я повторюсь в третий раз, чтобы не было сомнений никаких: я утверждаю, что **можно** узнать (по некоторым вопросам) есть ли консенсус. Вы  же мне приписываете **противоположную** точку зрения: вы пишите: *«Вы передёргиваете. Узнать, есть ли консенсус в сообществе по тому или иному вопросу, можно»* Итак для ясности: какова по вашему мнению, моё мнение о возможности определить есть консенсус или  нет?

Comment: по поводу снятия владельцев -- был или не был консенсус -- это отдельный вопрос -- не надо в сторону уводить¶ Всё относительно: вот в javascript чате кикнули и пошутили за счёт человека, который поднял вопрос, что не стоит о проститутках говорить на SE ресурсах (таких как javascript чат), что это может отталкивать некоторых людей.

Answer (score 5):

#### А на основании чего?

Все собщества Stack Exchange саморегулируемые, и подобные сообщения тоже часть процесса саморегуляции, направленная (не упадите) на улучшение администрации. В чём все стороны заинтересованы.

Это *в первую очередь* публичное заявление о том, что **администрация действует не в соответствии с правилами** – чётко, уважительно и без колкостей, с конкретным примером и от лица пострадавшего. Призыв "уйти в отпуск" тут вторичен и предлагается как возможное решение.

**Удаление этого сообщения полностью может нанести ещё больший вред ресурсу** – это заглушит конфликт, не разрешив его, что только испортит отношения между администрацией и активными участниками сообщества, которые знают о существовании конфликта.

И поскольку призыв "уйти в отпуск" прямым текстом адресован довольно узкому кругу лиц, непонятно, чем он может существенно навредить сообществу. Каждое лицо в этом узком кругу вполне способно решить за себя, а остальных он и не касается.

Comment: Во-первых, а я вообще не хотел этот "конфликт" обсуджать именно здесь. Во-вторых, я не вижу здесь никакой логики. К примеру, про "улучшать администрацию" — вообще странная мысль. А почему бы не "поулучшать активных участников"? Я не к этому веду, просто почему не пойму логику этого предложения. Раз этот призыв второстепен, то давайте удалим его, остальное оставим, почему нет? Почему вы решили, что есть пострадавшие? Люди, которые что-то неугомонно доказывали в чате, не сильно стараясь именно общаться, а просто "качали права" — просто получили небольшой заслуженный бан, причём только в чате.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov (1) Понятия не имею, что вы хотели – вы привели пример, я объясняю пример. Если пример не отражает поднятой вами проблемы, выберите другой пример. (2) Чем "улучшение администрации" странная мысль? Так работает конструктивная критика: описывается конкретная проблема в надежде, что критикуемый попытается её решить или объяснить, почему она проблемой не является. Удалять призыв нельзя – это "противоречит намерениям автора", а веских поводов в пользу удаления в правилах нет: оскорблений, спама или явного неуважения в сообщении нет.

Comment: Вы считаете, что этот бан заслуженный? Так вот есть немало людей, которые так не считают. На момент удаления соответствующий ответ имел рейтинг +7/-2, в чём имеет возможность убедиться любой участник с 10к+ репутации.

Comment: Фраза-призыв "показать что будет с сообществом, без старичков. А потом посмотрим как будет идти рассуждение о полезности." — явное желание навредить сообществу через призыв в нём неучаствовать. А в этом я вижу потенциальный вред и не вижу никакого позитивного смысла в таких сообщениях.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov "желание навредить сообществу"? Скорее наоборот: желание показать, что администрация сама вредит сообществу, отталкивая участников, и что это стоит перестать делать, пока этот вред не стал ощутимым. Есть ваше мнение, есть моё, есть другие. Чьё вернее, решать ни мне, ни вам.

Answer (score 4):

Позвольте виновнику высказаться.

Во-первых, я благодарен Николасу за то, что после поспешного удаления, он внял-таки и вернул пост, пусть в виде комментария.
Во-вторых, в сообщении я высказал своё мнение, если уж мнения под запретом и подлежат удалению, то мне тут точно делать нечего.

Участникам конфликта действительно стоило бы выпустить пар, на эмоциях ничего дельного в плане правил не создадим.

Answer (score 1):

> TL;DR Обратная связь является безусловным благом для администрации
>   ресурса.

Построение любого крупного успешного сообщества невозможно без выстраивания обратной связи. В случае stackoverflow мы имеем дело как с сообществом саморегулируемым, так и управляемым центральной администрацией.

[См. например](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/213987) "вопросы управления сайтом и сообществом" чётко делятся на :

> - Вопросы, решения в которых принимают участники демократически.
> - Вопросы, решения в которых принимает компания единолично, опираясь на отзывы сообщества.

Поэтому ответ на вопрос "допустима ли на ресурсе призывать не пользоваться этим ресурсом" вы получите дважды: один раз "от сообщества" (проактивной части, которая привыкла высказывать своё мнение на мете) и "от администрации" (которая, разумеется обладает исключительными правами и имеет возможность любой вопрос объявить областью единоличной ответственности компании).

В этой теме ещё не появлялись представители администрации и не дали своего ответа, поэтому я попробую как высказать своё личное мнение, так и попробовать объяснить как считаю вести себя правильным в зависимости от принятого решения администрации,  того или иного.

Лично за себя могу сказать, что мой выбор именно stackoverflow по сравнению с сайтами-конкурентами был во многом предопределён именно тем фактором, что на so позиционировал себя как высокоорганизованное сообщество профессионалов, которые не только собственно в программирование умеют, но ещё и строят эффективные общественные [клубы](http://www.adolgin.ru/online/). Миссия сайта - создать базу знаний - возможна разными вариантами, например есть база знаний MSDN. Или тостер - был же даже реалистичный вариант, что хэшкод станет частью холдинга тематические медиа.

Так вот для меня очевидно, что обратная связь - благо как для участников, так и для руководства. Мы живём в постоянно изменяющемся мире, поэтому всегда должны либо предпринимать какие-то действия - и постоянно сверяться с компасом ("миссией"): туда ли мы идём, правильно ли поступаем.

Если мы разделяем миссию организации, если мы видим, что те или иные действия ведут не туда наше и право и обязанность дать обратную связь об этом.

> Принцип регулирования по обратной связи гласит, что чем больше
>   расхождение цели и текущего курса - тем сильнее должен быть сигнал
>   обратной связи.

Именно поэтому нет ничего крамольного в том, что на сильное отклонение должны подаваться всё более сильные сигналы: если ваш сигнал игнорируется (курс остаётся прежним), то ваша обязанность предупредить сильнее. Если ваш рулевой вас не слышит и держит курс на скалы то не надо говорить об ответственности за слова ("Свобода должна идти бок-о-бок с ответственностью", "они могут принести потенциальный вред данному ресурсу" и т.п.), надо кричать громче, чтобы услышали.

Если дело дошло до того, что по обратной связи о неправильном курсе говорит не один человек, а множество (и среди них много активистов сайта, старожилов сайта и людей с весомой репутацией) - это отчётливый сигнал, что что-то не ладно в королевстве.

Может случиться одно из двух. Либо ошибаетесь вы (вам навтыкают минусов и другие участники меты и ещё прилетит от администрации - "не вносите шум"), либо ошибается всё огромное сообщество (такое тоже бывало, когда огромная империя слилась за три дня). Вы сами вправе решать, что делать уже с этой вторичной обратной связью: толи тихо покинуть сообщество, которое летит на скалы, толи пересмотреть свою позицию.

В любом случае время всё расставит по местам. Любой кризис проявляет противоречия и сколько их не заметай под ковёр они станут явными и могут привести к риску гибели организации.

Лично я считаю, что мета - это прекрасный инструмент для обратной связи (со своими недостатками, но ничего лучше у нас пока нет). Видите что идёт что-то неправильное - дайте тут же обратную связь на мете. Заметьте: не в почту управляющему - а на мете: посмотрите, сколько человек вам поставят плюсы (или минусы), какие будут комментарии. Одна голова (пусть это даже голова управляющего сообществом) хорошо, а десятки - лучше.

Что до действий администрации. В условиях когда администрация получает негативный сигналы, но предпочитает их по каким-либо причинам игнорировать - вы можете получить и такую же негативную реакцию в ответ.

Власть и сила на их стороне, могут как просто отмахнуться, так и применить репрессивные меры. Скажем забанить. Тот, кто приходит с негативом (причём необоснованным - а как иначе, если ваши вести игнорируют, а не прислушиваются: значит считают необоснованными) воспринимается как враг или как сумашедший. А какое отношение к врагам? Нейтрализация и ответная агрессия. (Всё ещё проще, если вы не можете усиливать обратную связь не переходя на более экспрессивные выражения. Вас вежливо попросят не ругаться, быть конструктивными и забанят)

Можно ли быть демократическими с врагами? Наверное, можно - но проще забанить. Или любые другие действия, например поделить протестующих (пишите мне лично на почту, не надо идти на мету), проводить квазидемократические процедуры и т.п.

Возможно я расстрою вас, но в условиях когда идёт атака (именно так это и воспринимается) на организацию первое, что нужно сделать - это подавить бунт и вернуть управляемость. Возможно, вам уже на тот момент окончательно забаненому будет приятно, что ваша обратная связь была учтена (посмертно) и не вам пожинать эти плоды? В любом случае помните, что фаза учёта обратной связи может предваряться стадией наведения порядка и там будет не очень много демократии. (Кстати, попробуйте создать свой сайт и удивитесь, как быстро сообщество захочет выйти из под вашей опёки. Дети - они почему-то совсем не любят, когда мы им навязываем как им жить. Говорят "мы свободные", предствляете?)

Призывы "уйдём с so" - однозначно несут вред сообществу и на основании этого применение силы к смутьянам легко может быть обосновано.

Будет ли? Не знаю - подождём официального ответа. Я к сожалению оптимист и часто ошибаюсь в хорошем, но мне почему-то кажется, что у нас есть шанс услышать друг друга.

Comment: "Обратная связь является безусловным благом для администрации ресурса." Мне тут слово "безусловным" сильно смущает. Вот [пример обратной связи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3776/220571) — там много "приятного" про нашу администрацию. Вы уверен, что это благо именно "безусловно"? Или всё-таки условия есть?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov тут речь про само наличие механизма обратной связи, а не что каждый сигнал идущий по ней - благо.